# Work with Power BI Matrix taking data from DAX statement

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have the following requirements:

- The user will see a Power BI Matrix on a web page (as opposed to Power BI Desktop).
- The web page should have three elements: a text field, a button and the Power BI Matrix (potentially included in a Power BI Report).
- The user will enter the DAX statement in the text field and click on the button to direct the Matrix to take the DAX statement, execute it, and populate the data.
- The user should be able to drill down in the Matrix.
- The user may reenter a new DAX statement, refreshing the Matrix.

Now, all the documentation I could find, for example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/visuals/desktop-matrix-visual), talk about the Matrix in Power BI Desktop (i.e. not web page) and the data taken by selecting manually tables/columns/measures (on the right side of the screen).

In Power BI Studio, I know that I can enter a DAX statement by creating a table in the top bar, for example if I have the DAX:

```
 EVALUATE TOPN (3, branches)
```

I could create a table to populate the Matrix with:

```
BranchesTable = TOPN (3, branches)
```

But how to dynamically link a DAX statment defined at run-time to a Matrix on a web page?

Comment: what kind of DAX statement would you expect to enter? Are you using `DirectQuery` or static dataset? If you need few predetermined views (e.g. TopN branches, where user provides the N), then you can achieve it without repopulating the data

Comment: @Stachu It could be any valid DAX statement. I'm using DirectQuery and SQL Server as the data store. Once the user enters the DAX statement, the aplication should analyze what are the columns in the resulting table and populate the Matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not currently possible to do exactly what you want. You can dynamically change a data source and update the query used in a specific report but there isn't an API available (PowerBI REST or  PowerBI JavaScript) to update what columns are on a visual in a report. You can get pretty close to what you want but the report cannot be displayed in `View` mode and it will have to be displayed in `Edit` mode so the user will have the ability to drag the fields generated from their updated DAX query results onto the Matrix visual manually if they submit a change.

Assuming you already have the pre-requisite App Registration setup and configuration completed and your ready to embed here are some steps to get close to what your looking for. If your not ready to embed there is some documentation below the 8 steps I provided to complete the pre-requisite setup to be able to embed.

1. Using PowerBI Desktop Create a template report that has a matrix visual and a connection to the data source you want to use. **Be sure to set this report up using a specific query and NOT all tables in the data source whether its SQL or SSAS.** (You specify the query under advanced options when you initially setup the data source in the report)
2. Setup a Power BI Data Gateway to the Data Source your report uses
3. Create a workspace on PowerBI.com to upload the report to
4. Using PowerBI desktop Publish the report you created in step 1 to the workspace you created in step 3
5. On your Web Application, when a user views the report viewer page, you need a way to identify each user. Lets assume you have `UserId` field that is a unique ID for each user. Call GetReports in group https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/reports/getreportsingroup. You need to have a known report name plus the UserId. Lets assume its DynamicReport. So call GetReports and check if `DynamicReport_UserId` exists for the user trying to view the report viewer page in your web application.
6. In that API calls result from step 5, if the report does not exist for a user, use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/reports/clonereport to clone the template report you published in step 4.
7. Embed and display user specific template report (DynamicReport_UserId) for the user.
8. Have logic on the report viewer page so the user can submit and `POST` a DAX query. When they do a submit have logic to use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/datasets/updatedatasources on the back end to update the data source in their report and then embed the report again with their DAX statement and changed data.

The visual isn't going to automatically update to the new fields from the new query that is submitted by the user but the available data fields they have in editor mode will change. The user will have to drag and drop the fields from their DAX query onto the Matrix visual or whatever visual type they are going to chose to use. You won't be able to just display a report in `View` mode since you don't have a way to programatically update what fields are on visual. The user may even end up seeing a broken visual initially because of the changed query and the visual referencing fields from the previously used query. You could use PowerBI Javascript API to hide the existing visual to improve the user experience of the user not seeing something broken.

Let me know if you have any specific questions about these API calls or how to use them.

Here is where I've been looking for the Power BI JavaScript functionality https://github.com/Microsoft/powerbi-javascript/wiki (Can't find anything specific to matrix Visuals. The JavaScript functionality for visuals generic to Visuals and not Visual Type like Matrix or Card)

Here is Microsoft's documentation on the available REST APIs and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/

Here are some good resources to learn more about embedding

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/register-app
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embedding

If you need drill down capability Hierarchies are a great option

https://spreadsheeto.com/power-bi-hierarchy/

Comment: @ps0604 This is going to be complex, but entirely possible. I fear that if you have one report, and update the data source query, that would effect other users looking at the same report at the same time.

Comment: @ps0604 I'm going to investigate but high level I think you can have a "template" report with the matrix visual you want and use that template to create other reports on the fly. This can be done calling the PowerBI API. When a user submits DAX from the website/webapp you need call the PowerBI API to use the template report and update the data source query to what the user provided and then display the new generated report and possibly delete it after they are done viewing. Some clean up mechanism.

Comment: can I have one report per user, and just a matrix on each report? Then I don't need to do clean up, only recreate the matrix every time the user loads the page

Comment: Yes you can have logic so the back end tries to open a user report and if it doesn't exist then create it. And then when the user tries to view the report again you can just re open the existing report and update it based on their input without needing to have clean up logic to delete it remove the reports. I'll type up what APIs to use it's going to take me a little bit of time..

Comment: One thing that is not clear is why the `user will have to drag the fields generated from their DAX query` does that mean that the process will have two steps (1) update the datasource, and (2) select what fields are displayed ? There's no Javascript API to manipulate the Matrix?

Comment: Your process can update the data source of the report changing it to the query they provided, your (1) from the above comment. But your (2) in the above comment, there is currently not a way to programmatically update the visual with the new/different field through the JavaScript or REST APIs which is why currently the user would need Edit mode so they can drag and drop the fields from their DAX query onto the visual. It is possible to use the JavaScript API to manipulate parts of a visual like filtering but not changing or applying new fields from a new or changed query.

Comment: Thanks, is there a link to the Javascript APIs that specifically manipulate the Matrix? I cannot find one.

Comment: At least can I clear the Matrix when the user runs the new DAX statement and discard the old fields?

Comment: There isn't specific JavaScript APIs for a Matrix visual that I have been able to find. Instead of at the visual type level like Matrix they are all generic at the visual level and could be applied to any visual type is what I am seeing. I don't think you can easily clear our the Matrix but you could hide it so the user doesn't see a broken visual.

Comment: @ps0604 you might also want to consider having some kind of validation or sanitation logic to make sure the user is submitting a valid DAX statement and also a statement that is safe to run. If they submit a bad DAX statement it could lead to a broken visual and no fields to select. You could identify that scenario and show an error message instead of letting them proceed. I've done my best to high level answer your question. Do you have any specific questions about how to proceed with any of the areas I outlined or any ideas for a differing approach you could share?

Comment: One last question, con you confirm that this will work on Azure Power BI?

Comment: @ps0604 yes all of this will work with Azure Power BI. That is how I am currently doing embedding for several web applications: We buy capacities on portal.azure.com and use powerbi.com to assign the capacities to workspaces and then do the embedding process.